# What is aloha app and what is process to make app as aloha

Tags: app-development, appexchange, app

Can you please help me understand what is Aloha SFDC app and how it differs from other apps ?

If app is developed based on force.com features only (no other services are used) does it gets considered as Aloha app?

What are steps/guidelines to make app as Aloha?

Answer (score 13):

I believe the terminology has changed from aloha apps to ISV apps.

Previously the main advantage was that installed ahola apps didn't count towards various org limits and could work with Group and Professional editions of Salesforce. In a previous Salesforce release at least some of the advantages were passed on to all managed packages.

Not much documentation appears to use the term "aloha" any more. There is an old blog post [Design an Aloha App](http://blogs.developerforce.com/systems-integrator/2010/04/design-an-aloha-app.html). The post linked to the [Designing an Application for Group and Professional Edition](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php?title=Designing_an_Application_for_Group_and_Professional_Edition&oldid=44312) page which now redirects to [Architectural Considerations for Group and Professional Editions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/dev_packages_for_pe_ge.htm). I pulled the following out of the wiki history for the old page:

> Furthermore, as part of the AppExchange Partner Program, your managed package will be eligible for special permissions allowing you to take advantage of unique benefits ensuring your app will properly install and function in GE and PE. Apps built on Force.com and which have these special permissions are called **Aloha Apps**. Aloha Apps will be featured on the AppExchange [here](http://sites.force.com/appexchange/results?type=Apps&filter=9&sort=6).
>
> Upon eligibility, an Aloha App is Apex authorized and immune to certain edition limits. In addition, if your app requires API integration, eligible partners can gain API access to GE and PE orgs. For more information on the Partner Program, including eligibility requirements, please visit us at www.salesforce.com/partners.
>
> **Note:** *Your app can only be an Aloha App and receive the Aloha App icon on your AppExchange listing if it's packaged as a managed package.*
>
> ## How to make an Aloha App?
>
> By now, you understand there's many special permissions you can take advantage to build for GE and PE. If you've built an app and you think it's ready to work with GE/PE as is, you can log a case at the [Partner Portal](http://www.salesforce.com/partnerportal) and create a case requesting any of the permissions mentioned (Apex Authorization, Apps/Objects/Tabs Limit Immunity, and/or API Access). Note that your application has to have a managed package associated with its listing and you must be an eligible partner. For more information on the Partner Program, including eligibility requirements, please visit us at www.salesforce.com/partners.
>
> Keep in mind you may still need to re-architect your app to support GE/PE, even with these special permissions active. As a partner, you are entitled to various test environments to ensure your app will work properly against GE/PE, you can learn more [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Partner_Development_&_Test_Environments).

I think going forward you are better following the documentation from [Using Apex in Group and Professional Editions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm)

Once you've ensured that your app meets the requirements for Aloha status, you then need to raise a case in the partner portal asking for it to be granted, it's *not* automatic. There's a specific case category available for such requests.

Comment: It seems that Aloha apps are (or were) apps that can run in GE or PE, and also don't count against typical limits - see https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h1rAAAQ

Comment: "You must be an eligible partner with salesforce.com and your app has to pass the security review. The appropriate permissions will automatically be enabled after you pass the security review." Aloha status is now automatic, according to the link in the answer.

Comment: Aloha, as it's still called by the LMA subscribers tab, still has implications on limits - most notably aloha enabled packages don't count against subscriber org tab limits.

Answer (score 7):

### What is Aloha:

Aloha was a special status given to apps so that the apps did not count against various limits imposed by Salesforce.  The benefits included:

- Aloha apps didn't count against Custom Apps, Objects, and Tabs limits
- Aloha apps could run Apex Code in Group Edition (GE) and Professional Edition (PE)
- Aloha apps could use the Web Service API for GE and PE

When Salesforce updated the AppExchange in August 2012, **Salesforce stopped publicizing the term "Aloha App."**

Since August 2012, all managed packages do not count against Salesforce system limits. Here's the Salesforce blog post announcing the change:

http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2012/08/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-new-salesforce-appexchange.html

### Requesting "Aloha" status:

In essence, Salesforce now considers all managed packages as Aloha.  So the only requirement for an app to be Aloha is that it be a managed package.

**However, you may still need to request "Aloha" status via the partner portal.**

Once you create your managed package, open a case with salesforce partner support and request that your package be "Aloha Enabled."  In your support case provide the following:

1. The package installation URL
2. The AppExchange Listing URL

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please don't ask for upvotes on answers; voting is an inherent part of the SE network and your answer *will* get voted up if it deserves votes.

As for saying they stopped using the term, they might have done so in public but when raising a case you still have to ask for Aloha status!

Comment: @LaceySnr Salesforce used to have special case in the partner portal for requesting Aloha status. That case type has been removed. Are you still submitting cases to request Aloha for apps?

Comment: I did one in June this year — without it our app wouldn't install in Professional Edition orgs due to some of the platform features our app uses. After the case was submitted and closed with the comment "Comment: I've aloha enabled this package." it worked as expected.

Comment: Under Subscriber Overview, it still says "Aloha App" with a checkbox. Our app has it, and it had to be manually enabled, although this was circa May 2012.

Comment: Strange my experience is that it has been removed from the case type for a while now (since the poorly worded August 2012 announcement about it going), but like other posters you still have to request it (via a vanilla case type in my case), having completed security review, which in turn requires you to be a Salesforce Partner.

Comment: Is "Aloha" status still a thing in 2020? @sfdcfox

Comment: @Robs Depends on how technical you want to be. The effect previously called Aloha Status still exists (managed package apps have special limit-busting features), but the term is no longer used, and no longer has a separate application process. Once your app meets the requirements (Partner status, Security Review, AppExchange listing), your app automatically gets the status effect with no additional request necessary.