# Salesforce Managed Package Installation Error

Tags: limits, error, app-install

I am getting the following Error when I try to Install managed package. I am uses the Professional Edition of Salesforce.

> 'Either you or your organization has exceeded the maximum number of
>   custom fields allowed in the system. Please contact your administrator
>   for more information.

Custom field limit for Professional Edition is 100 per Custom Object.
As fields are from Manged Package, they should not be counted for the
Custom Object

Comment: Making a package managed sadly does not make it exempt to custom field limits.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am not able to install Package directly to Professional Edition.. First I need to older version of package than I can upgrade the older version with newer version which have only 1 new custom field Added to Custom Object

Comment: Upgrading Older to newer version is not raising any error. This is so strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit labour intensive, but might be quicker than waiting for support to tell you which object custom field limit you have exceeded. That said, you will still need to ask support to increase the applicable limit if you can't delete any existing custom fields.

1. Create a new blank Development Org
2. Install the managed package there
3. For each object that gets custom fields installed, note how many the managed package requires.
   Setup > App Setup > Customize > [Object. E.g. Opportunities] > Limits.
   [image: Custom Field Limits]
4. Compare this limit with the available capacity in your professional edition org.

   - Note 1: Not all managed packages have independent limits from the installing org.
   - Note 2: It might be quicker to scan the limits using
     https://*pod*.salesforce.com/p/setup/custent/EntityLimits?type=Opportunity
     Just change *pod* to match your server instance and change the type query string parameter as required.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your response but I can not see Custom Field usages are counted. I can see only 2 custom fields created on the object

Comment: So when you installed the managed package in a blank dev org it only required 2 custom fields? Which object was this on? It might be that other objects also required custom fields.

Comment: Daniel, It is a custom object and contains more than 100 custom fields but as they are in managed package it is not counting against organization limit. I am able to install that package in Development and Enterprise organization but not in professional edition. After Installation in Dev and Enterprise , I can not see any of the field counted as for the Limit.

Comment: Not all managed packages are exempt for the limits of the installing org. See [What is aloha app and what is process to make app as aloha](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12118/what-is-aloha-app-and-what-is-process-to-make-app-as-aloha)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to file a support case for this.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for your response.
How do i file a support case ?

Comment: Ok.. I googled that. I will open a case.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify one point that I didn't see covered in the other answers:

Managed packages are only exempt from object, tab, and app limits IF the organization is part of the ISV program and the app is publicly posted on the app exchange (which requires passing security review). [Documentation here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/index_Left.htm#CSHID=dev_package_limits_for_pe_ge.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fdev_package_limits_for_pe_ge.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp). If the package is not listed on the app exchange it'll still affect your limits.

Also, sometimes something goes wrong with Salesforce and the owner of the managed package has to raise a support case to have the latest version of their package correctly not affect limits.