# Managed packages governor limits

Tags: governorlimits

Is salesforce more lenient towards managed packages? I mean do they let the code in managed packages get better governor limits?

Also, What should I choose? Managed packaging or Unmanaged packaging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that a managed package can be given its own set of governor limits that are separate from the governor limits of other managed packages and unmanaged code in the org. So they are not "better" in the sense of being higher, they are just separately counted. So if each managed package adds a trigger to Account, there is less risk of the work done in each managed package adding up to a governor limit exception on Account.

A managed package does not automatically operate that way and you could start your further research on that subject say here [What is aloha app and what is process to make app as aloha](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12118/what-is-aloha-app-and-what-is-process-to-make-app-as-aloha).

The managed/unmanaged choice involves many factors. If you believe you are developing a product that you have a stable design for, that many customers will install, that will go through a series of enhancements, and that you want to promote via the AppExchange then managed is the right choice. But going the managed route has a learning curve (and cost) and you should do plenty of reading on the subject before taking any decision.