# Trouble Installing new 2GP Managed Package from App Exchange

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, 2gp, package-install

I have developed a managed package that integrates our web application into Salesforce.  I recently moved to 2GP packaging and have the new listing active after recently passing Security Review.  I have been developing additional features as it was in Security Review for a while.  I have installed into the partner Enterprise and Professional edition orgs with no problem.  I added those additional features (custom permissions, App Page, feature parameters, etc), created a new minor version, upgraded the linked solution to my listing, and now I am showing the following error when trying to install in our Essentials Edition production org.

*Missing feature
Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Apex Classes* (in fact got it many times over; even on Apex Classes that I have previously installed before in this org).

I have never run across this before when installing into our production org, while I am still able to successfully install from our listing into our Partner Enterprise and Professional Editions.

Is this something related to 2GP Packaging?
Is this a configuration issue on our listing since I thought a managed package (once it passes security review) can be installed in any edition?
Or, is this not true and only some features can be installed into Essentials Edition?
Or is it something else entirely?

I want to be sure that it is not something that will cause our customers issues before releasing into the wild.

Any help???

Comment: Check [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm).

Answer (score 3):

The ability to run Apex code is limited in Group and Essential Editions to Managed Packages that have "[Aloha status](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/12118/2984)" (whatever they call it today). This permission is what allows managed packages to exceed certain limits (max fields per object, etc) as well as the ability to run Apex Code. While some people believe that this is granted automatically as part of the Security Review process, it is an extra checkbox or something that has to be toggled independently, and sometimes the Partner Support team doesn't do this for various reasons. And, like all things human, sometimes they just forget to by accident. Your best case is to contact Partner Support, as they should be able to fix your package for you.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox.  This helps A LOT.  I had previously seen the doc that Phil W linked to above and believe I am in compliance with all of those considerations but thought I might be missing something. I have an on-going case for this and will bring up the Aloha/ISV Partner app status configuration as a possible cause.